# jsf How to filter results by given id

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Hi I have the following problem, I have table in which I show a list of companies, I would like filter that list in suach a way that the user only get to see a list of companies created by him.
Heres the table

```
<h:dataTable value="#{empresaController.items}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
 <h:column>
    <h:graphicImage rendered="#{not empty item.logo}"
                    value="/resources/images/#{item.logo}" styleClass="covers"/>
</h:column>
 <h:column>
    <h:graphicImage rendered="#{not empty item.imagen}"
                    value="/resources/images/#{item.imagen}" styleClass="covers"/>
</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListEmpresaTitle_nombre}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.nombre}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListEmpresaTitle_descripcion}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.descripcion}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListEmpresaTitle_rubroidRubro}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.rubroidRubro.nombre}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandLink action="#{empresaController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListEmpresaViewLink}"/>
        <h:outputText value=" "/>
        <h:commandLink action="#{empresaController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListEmpresaEditLink}"/>
        <h:outputText value=" "/>
        <h:commandLink action="#{empresaController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListEmpresaDestroyLink}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

and here is my controller:

```
private FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
private UsuarioController usuarioController = (UsuarioController) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{usuarioController}", UsuarioController.class);



    private EmpresaFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}

public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
    if (pagination == null) {
        pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return getFacade().count();
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
            }
        };
    }
    return pagination;
}

public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
}

public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
}

public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableByUser() {
    List<Empresa> empByUsuarios = new ArrayList<Empresa>();

    for(Empresa emp: ejbFacade.findAll()){
        if(emp.getUsuarioidUsuario().getIdUsuario() 
                == usuarioController.getSelected().getIdUsuario()){
            empByUsuarios.add(emp);
        }
    }       
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(empByUsuarios, false);
}
```

How do I call getItemsAvailableByUser when the user wants to see that list?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try to replace `<h:dataTable value="#{empresaController.items}" ... />` with `<h:dataTable value="#{empresaController.itemsAvailableByUser}" ... />`. When the user want to switch between lists, well, it's a managed bean, so set a property in there and add another method, that returns (dependent from the property) either the one or the other list.

Comment: @L-Ray Not following you, could you please elavorate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
    if (pagination == null) {
        pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return getItemsAvailableByUser().length;
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                return new ListDataModel(findRangeByUser(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
            }
        };
    }
    return pagination;
}
public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableByUser() {
    List<Empresa> empByUsuarios = new ArrayList<Empresa>();

    for(Empresa emp: ejbFacade.findAll()){
        if(emp.getUsuarioidUsuario().getIdUsuario() 
                == usuarioController.getUserSession().getUser().getIdUsuario()){
            System.out.println(emp.getUsuarioidUsuario().getNombre());
            empByUsuarios.add(emp);
        }
    }       
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(empByUsuarios, false);
}

public List<Empresa> findRangeByUser(int[] range){
    List<Empresa> empByUsuarios = new ArrayList<Empresa>();

    for(Empresa emp: ejbFacade.findAll()){
        if(emp.getUsuarioidUsuario().getIdUsuario() 
                == usuarioController.getUserSession().getUser().getIdUsuario()){
            System.out.println(emp.getUsuarioidUsuario().getNombre());
            empByUsuarios.add(emp);
        }
    }
    if(empByUsuarios.size() > 10){
        empByUsuarios.subList(range[0], range[1] - range[0]);
    }
    return empByUsuarios;
}
```

I duplcauted the controller (backing bean) and made those changes, the down side is that I have 2 controllers practically identical, any ideas on how to avoid this is welcome

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to delegate the change to another method and change your list of items to the one  `getItemsAvailableByUser` returns. Something like this:

```
public class Controller {

   private SelectItem[] items;
   // getter, setter

   public void changeItems() {
       items = getItemsAvailableByUser(); 
   } 

}
```